# Extracting IPv4 address from docker inspect bridge

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to get the list of IPv4Address assigned to each container added to the bridge.

I am trying to use `docker network inspect bridge  --format='{{((index .Containers))}}'`. However, I am not able to index 0, 1, 2 and parse the IPv4Address.

```
test$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "5b1a2e317cae4ed0086400d7ef9901a793d951bc5f5e7b6c678747d9b5c0f891": {
                "Name": "test0",
                "EndpointID": "d6a2524ef8e0eb75726d5482c30f6cc2ee8ba70544463720259939250b886cc1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:f0:7f:01:02",
                "IPv4Address": "240.127.1.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "bc087f0ba588e0da94053b5122e05f0cb0633c7e5745fe519576fd6e388d7df7": {
                "Name": "test2",
                "EndpointID": "598c2a57a85cda1bbd9a478da3d0b36d74b7ad0a24372fa6206ef3fc3283b631",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:f0:7f:01:03",
                "IPv4Address": "240.127.1.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d51198ea4aab32a7ea0bfee24bb2df4db700dd6a3ec88174141ec25f66e19946": {
                "Name": "test1",
                "EndpointID": "f82dacdfd65c29b85ae7ece5e59e7083cd4de3bc72814443d73cbc01be175cd0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:f0:7f:01:04",
                "IPv4Address": "240.127.1.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },

        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: To what end?  (The container-private IP addresses are unreachable except in one very specific Docker/host combination; there are better ways to reach containers that don't require knowing them.)  What have you tried so far, and what results are you getting?

Comment: I want to reach them via the host itself. I have tried this `docker network inspect bridge  --format='{{((index .Containers "5b1a2e317cae4ed0086400d7ef9901a793d951bc5f5e7b6c678747d9b5c0f891" "IPv4Address"))}}' `. However, instead of giving the container uuid, i was wondering if there way to index

Comment: @DavidMaze I need to run servers in the 3 containers each in its own namespace. From another container in the host namespace if I need to set up connections to each of the 3 servers, how can I get the IP-addresses?

Comment: You can use the `docker run -p` option to publish a port to the host, and then access the containers using the host's IP address (or possibly `localhost`) and the published port.  The container-private IP addresses don't work from Windows, or MacOS, or on Docker Toolbox, or from other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The `--format` option takes a [Go template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). If you want to iterate over the `.Containers` map, you can do it with the [`range`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables) action. For instance:

```
{{ range $containerIndex, $data := .Containers }}{{ $containerIndex }} - {{ $data.IPv4Address }}{{"\n"}}{{end}}
```

yields something like

```
161a4657d65738907ab1d09d00ad38dd134a5c9ea7f346387cce50281f31f900 - 172.20.0.2/16
```